# yii2 dataprovider getcount with pagination

Tags: yii2

suppose i have 10 row of data in DB and when i use search function in search model

suppose ill get 10 results when i call below function

```
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        ]);

$dataProvider->getCount() --- in view i get 10
```

and if i set pageSize=5

```
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 5),
        ]);

     $dataProvider->getCount() --- in view i get 5
```

ill get count 5 on each page.

is there anyway to get total count on every page??

Comment: Consulting the guide always helps - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$dataProvider->getTotalCount();
```